Implementing a silent mode of iPhone in my react project for ironSource
I need to implement my react app project for ironSource, and i'm struggling with one problem. I have an mediaPlayer in my project, that looks like this:
const VideoPlayer = () => {

  const [muted, setMuted] = useState(true);

  const handleVideoInteraction = () => {
    if (muted) {
      setMuted(false);
    } else {
      openStore();
      document.getElementById("myVideo").pause();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={s.playerWrapper} onClick={handleVideoInteraction}>
      {showBlur && (
        <div className={s.blurWrapper} onClick={openStore}>
          <div className={`${s.blur}`} />
          <p className={s.tapToSee}>tap to see more</p>
        </div>
      )}

      <video
        className={`${s.video}}
        width="430"
        height="730"
        autoPlay
        muted={muted}
        playsInline
        id="myVideo"
      >
        <source
          src=<videoSrc>
          type="video/webm"
        />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
};

its inside of my app:
export default VideoPlayer;
const App = () => {
  const muteVideo = (volume) => {
    const mediaElements = document.querySelectorAll("audio, video");

    mediaElements.forEach((element) => {
      if (volume > 0) {
        element.muted = true;
      } else {
        element.muted = false;
      }
    });
  };
  window.muteAllVideo = muteVideo;
  return <Playable />;

and then i have mandatory event listener for ironSource Network 'audioVolumeChange'
i'm trying to do this:
   dapi.addEventListener("audioVolumeChange", (volume) =>
      audioVolumeChangeCallback(volume)
    );
  }
  function audioVolumeChangeCallback(volume) {
    window.muteAllVideo(volume);
  }



Idea is that this event fires when user tries to mute app via iPhone switcher and this must mute my app, but in reality sound does not mute. I keep getting one response from ironSource QA
Critical bugs: Issue on all devices: Creative is playing sound even though the player mute button is enabled. To fix this issue make sure to add a listener to the audioVolumeChange event, read more on our DAPI implementation guideline (link: https://developers.is.com/ironsource-mobile/general/interactive-requirements/
I tried everything already. Maybe someone here can help, please.
I keep getting one response from ironSource QA
Critical bugs: Issue on all devices: Creative is playing sound even though the player mute button is enabled. To fix this issue make sure to add a listener to the audioVolumeChange event, read more on our DAPI implementation guideline (link: https://developers.is.com/ironsource-mobile/general/interactive-requirements/
